# what does "deliver" mean in the context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

You go to a store and buy a product that sounds like it's the best deal. But then you get it home, and it doesn't deliver.

What does deliver mean here? Does it mean **It doesn't work as you expected**?

Comment: **[Deliver](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/deliver)** : *to do what you promised to do or what you are expected to do; to produce or provide what people expect you to* (OALD)

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  The implication is that it did not "deliver on" its promise; that it did not live up to expectations. Maybe it "worked", but not as advertised. In any case, It did not perform as you had hoped.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consult [a dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deliver). Obviously, in your example sentence, the verb *deliver* is used intransitively. Therefore, we skip all the meanings listed under *transitive verb* and get to:

> *intransitive verb*
>
> :  to produce the promised, desired, or expected results

Ta-daa

Comment: As the OED will confirm the verb *deliver* has multiple meanings, the first being to 'set free' or 'liberate'. The actual, slightly metaphorical, sense to which this question relates is actually meaning 8(d). Its first example of use is from this interesting quotation from 1959: *1959   F. Astaire Steps in Time (1960) xxi. 244,   I have a horror of not delivering—making good, so to speak; and I can't stand the thought of letting everybody down—studio and public as well as myself*